# Xamarin.Forms "Attribute "mapType" already defined with incompatible format." Error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

When I build app, I getting that error. I could not cause of this. Help me please!

[image]

Thats files in the cache folder, I'm deleting cache files, but thats being created when I build.

Comment: If you don't provide any more information we're not able to help you. Show us your code.

Comment: Whats in the corresponding XML file?

Comment: Just getting this error as well.  Thsi is under maps_attrs.xml in the Android specific project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I ran into this one when upgrading a Xamarin.Forms project from 1.4.x to 2.3.x.

The version of Google Play Services updated and changed to require less packages.  Go into your package manager and make sure that only these 3 GPs packages are installed:

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement, Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps

All version 29.0.0.1 are installed.

You may have: Xamarin.GooglePlayServices version 22.0.0.2 installed, delete that and it will work.